# $.ajax post empty data to server with jsonp

Tags: php, jquery

this below code could'nt send data to other server. i want to send `"aaa-bbb-ccc"` with $.ajax. but after post back `userCode` thats post empty data from $_POST. sorry for my english

jquery code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "http://www.site.com/index.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "jsonp",
        data: {userCode: "aaa-bbb-ccc"}
    }).done(function(data){
        alert(data.message);
    });
});
</script>
```

server index.php :

```
<?php
include_once ('./AFactory.class.php');
$database= new AFactory;
$db=new AFactory();
$link=$db->getDBO();
if ( $_POST['userCode'] == '')
{
    $data['success']=false;
    $data['message']='ERROR ...';
}
else {
    $query=array('id'=>NULL,'userCode'=>$_POST['userCode']);
    $sql=$db->insertQuery('`alachiq_takhmis`.`users`',$query);
    if ( mysql_query($sql) ) 
        {
            $data['success']=true;
            $data['message']=$_POST['userCode']; 
        }
    else 
        {
            $data['success']=false;
            $data['message']=$_POST['userCode'];
        }
}
echo $_GET['callback'] . '('. json_encode($data) . ')';
?>
```

post back:

```
({"success":false,"message":'ERROR ...'})
```

whats my code problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSONP works by injecting a `<script>` element with a `src` attribute into a document.

That can only ever make a GET request.

Comment: Rewrite it to use GET or XHR.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://www.site.com/index.php",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    data: {userCode: "aaa-bbb-ccc"}
});
```